# is it possible to create base EF DbContext and use it in many services?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, microservices

I try to implement Microservice Architecture in my project. I was wondering can i create 1 method for Depedency Injection there is to implement EntityFrameworkCore in many services so i didnt DRY.

So what iam thinking is i still create my own DbContext, and than when i want to register this i just put it in my json file and add something like `services.UseSql()` in my `startup.cs` and inside `UseSql`  is using Configuration from `.json` file.

what i try to say is something like generic `DbContext`.

I have some example to this but is using MongoDb :

**Example**

```
public static void AddMongo(this ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Register(context =>
        {
            var configuration = context.Resolve<IConfiguration>();
            var options = configuration.GetOptions<MongoDbOptions>("mongo");

            return options;
        }).SingleInstance();

        builder.Register(context =>
        {
            var options = context.Resolve<MongoDbOptions>();

            return new MongoClient(options.ConnectionString);
        }).SingleInstance();

        builder.Register(context =>
        {
            var options = context.Resolve<MongoDbOptions>();
            var client = context.Resolve<MongoClient>();
            return client.GetDatabase(options.Database);

        }).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        builder.RegisterType<MongoDbInitializer>()
            .As<IMongoDbInitializer>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        builder.RegisterType<MongoDbSeeder>()
            .As<IMongoDbSeeder>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
```

Comment: Each micro service should have its own data, so there will be no DbContext or Entity classes to share

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem statement correctly, you want multiple microservices to connect to the same database. As comments above suggest, you really shouldn't do that as you'd essentially be coupling your microsrvices through your data layer - which can be messy if your microservices grow into incompatible data layers. This would eliminate a lot of benefits of the architecture and leave you to deal with pains. So if that is indeed the case you might want to consider revisiting your arсhitecture and trying to figure out whether you need a new microservice that fronts this common data store and provides it to others.

In reality however you sometimes must share code between projects and there's a official way to do that: extract the common code [into a nuget package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package), host it somewhere in your private enterprise repository (if you care) and reference it from your other projects.